# iOS6 Get List of Street by first symbols

Tags: ios, mapkit

I just playing with MapKit and it's going well. If we looking at Native App (Maps) there are possible to find direction between two places. What is intresting for me - how they get list of Street when you type name? There are in SDK some possibility to get Streets list by couple of symbols?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a Map Kit expert but I recommend you review the Map Kit Framework (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) and especially the `MKLocalSearch` Class Reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012893) which allows you to search for addresses in a region.  I'm not aware of any API that allows you to retrieve ALL the streets in a region but `MKLocalSearch` will return the equivalent of a search in the Map app.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what i need! I can't add raiting...

Comment: I will add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Map Kit expert but I recommend you review the [Map Kit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) and especially the [MKLocalSearch Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012893).

The `MKLocalSearch` class allows you to search for addresses in a region as an equivalent of a search in the Map app. I'm not aware of any API that allows you to retrieve ALL the streets in a region.

Comment: still can't :) have low rank. Thank bro, downloading 6.1 sdk for try this feature... look nice, hope it's similar with google maps

Comment: The Apple Maps (and SDK) improve with every release; and the latest additions in iOS 6.1 plus the fact that the maps display without additional marketing (unlike Google Maps) make it a no-brainer to use first

Answer (score 0):

MKLocalSearch is the best and easiest way to do instant search of google maps,i have done it and its awesome and very simple